# rxjs version issue (two versions required)

Tags: npm, dependencies, rxjs

I have an ionic app which use some dependencies, but I have issues with rxjs because there are two versions of rxjs required:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

package.json (dependency parts):

```
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "firebase": "^3.6.5",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "@types/request": "0.0.30",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the `rxjs@5.0.1` specified in `package.json` of your project? This means you're trying to use `rxjs@5.0.1` and `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12` at the same time.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, angularfire needs 5.0.1, angular and ionic angular needs 5.0.0-beta12

Comment: Can you dump your `package.json`?

Comment: Btw, `angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.6` requires `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12` so you could switch to this version until it's updated for the newer `rxjs` version (see https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.6/package.json).

Comment: Thanks! This resolved my probelm.

Comment: please post this as an answer and it can be accepted to make it more useful.